# Python Tkinter Attribute Error

Tags: python, tkinter

I have made a tkinter program where i keep getting this error:

```
File "F:\Programming 2\Gui\Gui #11.py", line 78, in shape_workit
cylinder(pos=(0,0,0),axis=(1,0,0),color=self.color3.get(),

AttributeError: 'Kinter' object has no attribute 'color3'
```

Here is the code which the error occurs from:

```
def shapescolor(self):
    if self.color1.get()=="Does a Orange":
        color3=color.orange
    if self.color1.get()=="Does a Blue":
        color3=color.blue
def shape_workit(self):  
    try:
        if self.shape.get()=="Does a Cylinder":                         #Creates Cylinder
            cylinder(pos=(0,0,0),axis=(1,0,0),color=self.color3.get() ##ERROR HERE,
                     radius=float(self.radius.get()))
```

Here is the Code where the error it gets from

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you need to be doing `self.color3 = ...` rather than `color3 = ...`, since you're later refering to `self.color3` and haven't set that attribute anywhere else in the code you posted.